# NSFetchedResultsController section grouping by dynamic condition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have 2 entities in CoreData (which are relevant to this). Let's call them `objectA` and `objectB`. Each entity has a to-many relationship with the other entity.

I have a view which uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` to present a list of all `objectB` objects (records) in a table. That all works.

Now, what I'm trying to do is, given *any **one*** `objectA`, present a table with every `objectB` that has a relationship with **that specific** `objectA` in the first section, and the rest of them in the second section. From what I've tried, it seems `sectionNameKeyPath` in `NSFetchedResultsController` isn't flexible enough to allow for something like this.

Have I missed something, or are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that `NSFetchedResultsController` is not flexible enough for this, so I ended up using two `NSFetchedResultsController`s to separately fetch the first and second sections with different predicates.

Comment: I think you are trying to fight with NSFRC, managing two sections in table view having two NSFRC will be buggy as its designed to work with one FRC at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another solution,

create an attribute in ur entity (ex. sectionName or similar) which will be decided based on you condition, Ex. 'One' & 'Two'.

Now, when you create the FRC make it to create sections based on 'sectionName' (the new entry) with ascending.

Now you have two sections based on condition.

This is how I did it,

created a computed property in my core data entity subclass,

```
var groupSectionName:String?{
        return isPinned /**Or your condition*/ ? "One" : "Two"
    }
```

And while creating the FRC,

```
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context,    sectionNameKeyPath: "groupSectionName",cacheName: nil)
```

Now, for each index FRC will call the computed property.